# How to apply onClick event on Svg file on React?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I made a component for a Svg and I'm trying to apply onClick event so I change the state, but it doesnt work for some reason, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I tried applying the onCLick on  too , but it doesnt work either.

my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './style.scss'

const AverageSvg=() => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    
    <svg className="average"  onClick={() => setActive(false)} 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="170.539"
      height="51.974"
      viewBox="0 0 170.539 51.974"
    >
      <g data-name="The average" transform="translate(-1223 -2501)" >
        <g className={active ? "clicked-fill" : "fill "} 
          // fill="none"
          stroke="#707070"
          strokeWidth="1"
          data-name="Rectangle 60"
          transform="translate(1223 2501)"
        >
          <rect 
            width="170.539"
            height="51.974"
            stroke="none"
            rx="25.987"
          ></rect>
          <rect
            width="169.539"
            height="50.974"
            x="0.5"
            y="0.5"
            rx="25.487"
          ></rect>
        </g>
        <text className="text"
          // fill="#464646"
          data-name="The average"
          fontFamily="ArialMT, Arial"
          fontSize="17"
          transform="translate(1261 2532)"
        >
          <tspan x="0" y="0" >
            The average
          </tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
    
  );
}

export default AverageSvg;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried wrapping the `svg` with another tag like a `div` or `span` and attaching the `onClick` on that wrapper ?
Also inside the `setActive()` you should pass `true` instead of `false`.

Comment: Okay, I didnt see that I was passing the false twice thank you! I switched to true and it worked perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can warp the SVG in another tag as Alexader says, also you can pass the event to the child element in the SVG tag directly and it will work. but you should be aware of the browser compatibility
check this link from MDN web Docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/onclick
for example, this is an SVG delete icon

```
export const Delete = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24" className={props?.className} >
      <path onClick={props?.onClick} d="M7 21q-.825 0-1.412-.587Q5 19.825 5 19V6H4V4h5V3h6v1h5v2h-1v13q0 .825-.587 1.413Q17.825 21 17 21Zm2-4h2V8H9Zm4 0h2V8h-2Z" />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

when you call it just `<Delete onClick={yourEvent} />`
the onClick will apply on the `<path/>` tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33320396)